# Apache - how to serve from a directory inside home folder, whereas home folder doesn't has any public permissions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-2.2

I'm using Apache2 for completely local development purposes. I'm trying to make `DocumentRoot` to be `/home/vikrant/www/` whereas permissions of `/home/vikrant/` are `700`.

I'm getting `403 Forbidden` when `DocumentRoot` is `/home/vikrant/www/` however *It Works!* when `DocumentRoot` is `/var/www/`.

I've even changed permissions of `/home/vikrant/www/` to `777` and changed *owner* and *group* to `www-data`.

Is it possible to serve from home directory whereas home directory doesn't has public permissions? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 2):

You need at least 711 permissions on `/home/vikrant`. A user has to have execute rights (+x or 1) on a directory to access anything under it.

Comment: good 4 hours yesterday trying to make this work, AI, Google, nobody would have any feedback that all it took was this on the userfolder. WOW. Thank you ptman

Answer (score 1):

Link your /Var/www/ to your home wikrant www and make sure the apache daemon owner has read permisions on that folder.

ln -s /home/vikrant/www /var/www/vikrant
chmod -R g+w /var/www/vikrant

ls -alt /var/www/vikrant   # check which group is the owner.

ps axu|grep apache2    # check the owner of the apache daemon.

add the owner of the apache daemon to the group which owns the /var/www/vikrant files.

Comment: It still didn't work.

Comment: which user is running apache?  #lets call it apache_user#
can you do login as apache_user through root?  
> sudo su
> su apache_user
then use cat and ls to check if it can read your files.
it is possible that you need to add +x to the directories previous to your files.

Answer (score 0):

Check your configuration a bit deeper.  Your default Apache setup is probably installed as simply *not* allow traffic to /.  For that matter, it's probably only configured to allow traffic to /var/www.

In addition to setting directory permissions (and as the dude above me said, you'll need at least execute on other to traverse the directory), you want to make sure that you have something like the following configured:

```
    
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
```

If you follow the above solution and just create a symbolic link from /var/www back to your home directory, you'll need to make sure Apache has been told that it's okay to follow symbolic links, by adding `FollowSymLinks` to the Options stanza for your existing document root.

Lastly, if you're using CGI under suExec, the symbolic link is your best bet as suExec has a compiled in "safe" path.  There's an easy way around that if you're using a Debian distro, though.

Yet another approach would be to just define a new name based virtual host that points to your home directory.